# Assign javascript CallBack function to a UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, javascript, updatepanel, callback

I wanna assign a **JavaScript CallBack function** to an **UpdatePanel** which will be gets called when the UpdatePanel **finishes** its tasks. After, the UpdatePanel will be sending a string as a result. This JavaScript CallBack function will have to process this resulting string.

Please help me out to achieve this.

Regards,
Akif

Comment: From a quick Google, I'm guessing UpdatePanel has to do with ASP.NET.  Added the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could register the [endRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx) event:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function(sender, args) {
    alert('async request finished');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but i knew it. My requirement is little bit different. I need to pass a string generated during partial postback of an updatepanel back to the browser. Then I will be processing this string in callback function.

Thnx
Akif